# Get more than just last insert ID using PDO / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am writing a small framework where my goal is to make it easy for my developers to set up a redirect to the details page of a resource after adding/inserting one.

Ordinarily this would be as easy as PDO::lastInsertID(), but I am using more than just the ID to identify the resource, I am also using a formatted version of the resource's name/title.

For example a new tournament might be called "Test Tournament" and therefore it's resource URI will be domain.com/tournament/328-test-tournament.

So when I redirect after inserting, I need to redirect to '328-test-tournament' and not just '328'. This is by design for URL integrity purposes. I don't want people accessing individual resources with mis-matched IDs and titles.

So that said, after I insert, I would like to be able to automatically return not just the ID, but the entire data set for what I entered, so that I can then format the title and redirect.

I could do this in the controller:

```
$this->TournamentModel->insert();

$id = PDO::lastInsertID();
$title = my_title_formatting_function($_POST['title']);
@header("Location: domain.com/tournament/{$id}-{$title}");
```

But I want a solution that's slightly more elegant like this:

$id = $this->TournamentModel->lastInsert();

Where lastInsert is actually a public method in the core model by retrieving not just the id of the last insert, but the entire row. I would then handle the title formatting and id concatenation right there.

Does something like this exist? Or at the very least is there a PDO method that returns the table that was inserted into so that I could construct a query using the table name and the id?

Comment: After insert, select all fields you want from last insert ID

Answer (score 1):

Check [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/).

They are two very famous Object Relational Mapper's, which have as base PDO.
[ORM's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) can do what you asked, and have lots of other features you will enjoy, check it up.

Answer (score 1):

Does a 'title' not belong to a `Tournament` object? i.e.

```
class TournamenentModel {
  private $id;
  private $title;

  public function setTitle($title) {
    $this->title = $title;
  }

  public function getTitleFormatted() {
    return my_title_formatting_function($this->title);
  }
}
```

in which case, your insert method might look something like

```
PDO::save(array('title' => $this->title));
```

and your workflow would be along the lines of:

```
$tournament = new TournamentModel();
$tournament->setTitle($_POST['title']);
$tournament->insert();

$title = $tournament->getTitleFormatted();
@header("Location: domain.com/tournament/{$id}-{$title}");
```

**The title is persisted in memory until you release the object**, there is no need to save and *then retrieve* it from a database?